# Ionic/Angularjs change controller to a global Variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is my controller:

```
(function () {

    var app= angular.module('app');
    app.controller('recommendedJobsCtrl', ['$scope', function(dataShare,$q,$scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate,$window,$http,$timeout) {

    // passes contents to jobDetails to be rendered and displayed
      window.post =  function($event, res){
        console.log(angular.element($event.target).parent());
        dataShare.sendData(res)
      }
  /**
    * handles pagination
    *loads first 3 pages
  **/
  var i=1; 
  window.result=[];
  window.noMoreItemsAvailable=false;
  window.loadMore =  function()
    {
      console.log('here')
      if(i<4)
      {
        $http.get( "http://test.website.com/api/search/"+i).success(function(response)
        {
          i++; 
          $scope.result=$scope.result.push(response); 
          console.log(response);

          $timeout(function () 
          {
          $scope.result = response
          });

          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
        });
      }else
      {
        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable=true; 
      }
    }

    ]);

}());
```

I read that my controller was under 'user strict' so it can't access the variables or functions. So I placed the word 'window' to make it global. But now it doesn't access the function because the console won't print. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency Injection is incorrect:

```
app.controller('recommendedJobsCtrl', [
  'dataShare',
  '$q', 
  '$scope', 
  '$ionicSideMenuDelegate', 
  '$window', 
  '$http', 
  '$timeout', 
  function(
    dataShare,
    $q,
    $scope,
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate,
    $window,
    $http,
    $timeout) {


   // Your code ...

}]);
```

Your code should be specific to the controller. You should create function and variables either on `$scope` as in `$scope.<functionName> = function() {}` and `$scope.noMoreItemsAvailable` or private to the controller as in `function <functionName>() {}` or `var noMoreItemsAvailable`.

In case intention behind using `window` object is to use same code across controllers, you may put this code in a `factory`.